# How to get the id of visible div inside scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have few div which comes in a main div with scrollbar.Here I need to get the id of visible div inside scrollbar on click of button.I don't have any idea about it,can any one please help me on this.here is the code below.

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>

<button>Click to get the current visible id</button><br>
<div id="mainbody">
<div id="div1">it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div><br>
<div id="div2">it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div><br>
<div id="div3">it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
</div>
```

### style

```
#mainbody{
height:70px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

### script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

    });
});
```

Comment: Given that multiple divs can be partially displayed in an area, what do you consider "visible" to be?

Comment: All 3 divs you've shown are visible, so ... ?

Comment: Why are you using `<br/>` at the end of your block elements?  They are not needed.

Comment: all 3 divs are visible but when you scroll, always one div will be  visible inside the scroll other is hiding right so I want the id of the div which is visible

Comment: What if 2 divs are partially "visible"?

Comment: SO you need to look at the positions and see if they are visible

Comment: But do they want the first one that is partially visible, the second one?  Both?  Or only if one is completely in view?  None of that has been clarified.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
      $("#mainbody").find("div:visible").each(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
      });
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#mainbody").find("div:visible").each(function(){
           alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>

<button>Click to get the current visible id</button><br>
<div id="mainbody">
<div id="div1">it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div><br>
<div id="div2">it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div><br>
<div id="div3">it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Given that the user is creating a scrollable area, it's a pretty easy assumption to make that they only want the ones that the user can see, aka, scrolled into view.  The outstanding question, is if two are partially scrolled into view, which one they want, or if they want both.  This answer does not cover any of that.  And side note, please don't encourage people to do `$(this).attr('id')`.  Just use `this.id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

const main = document.getElementById('mainbody')
const elementHeight = main.scrollHeight/3;

    $("button").click(function(){

            console.log(Math.floor(main.scrollTop / elementHeight) + 1)
    });
});
```

Here's working example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bj1a8ksr/

Comment: And when they do not have content that is equal?

Comment: What do you mean by 'they do not have content'?